# advanced EAV with sub-attributes in the value

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-attribute-value

Entity-Attribute-Value database tables are flexible ways to save properties of custom objects.

For my project, I must go beyond: I need to not only store fixed values of objects, I need to store the values as they change over time.

Like the length of a growing person:

- Entity: Peter
- Attribute: Length
- Value: 160cm at 1-1-2010, 170cm at 1-1-2011

It would be easy to solve by adding another column called "time".

But the idea is to be even more scalable, like this for example:

- Entity: Video
- Attribute: Tag
- Value: Peter at XY(100,200) at 0:20, at XY(200,300) at 0:30

So now the value not only has time, but also coordinates as extra sub-attributes. I want to be able to handle such sub-attributes.

The question is: Is there any default ultimately scalable known model for this? (So i dont have to re-invent the wheel)

Or should i just use a wrapper-entity around the entity in the value?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are saying that time and coordinates apply to *all* of your eav attributes.

In that case, it seems like the perfect solution would be to simply add `time` and `coordinates` (or x and y separately) to your eav table.

The whole reason to have eav is when you have a potentially unlimited number of attributes. But if there are some attributes that will be *super* attributes that apply to all others, there is no reason not to expand that eav table.

e.g.

```
id | entity_id | attribute  |  value  |  time    |  coordinates
1  |  25       | tag        |  funny  | 12/12/12 | 200,300
1  |  25       | tag        |  funny  | 12/13/12 | 0,1
```

You could then do a query like this:

```
SELECT `coordinates` FROM `my_table` WHERE `entity_id` = 25 ORDER BY `time` ASC
```

The result would be a set of coordinates that you could then plot on a graph or whatever, relating to a particular entity.

Or you could do:

```
SELECT `entity_id`, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`time`,'|',`coordinates`) ORDER BY `time` ASC SEPARATOR '~') as `time_coords` FROM `my_table` WHERE `entity_id` BETWEEN 25 AND 50 ORDER BY `entity_id`
```

That would give you a result like this

entity_id | time_coords
25        | 12/12/12|200,300~12/13/12|0,1
26        | 12/12/12|150,99~12/29/12|151,180~12/30/12|60,60

You could then use PHP (or whatever) to parse the result by entity_id.

E.g. (after you get back the query result)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  $id = $row[0];
  $time_coords = explode('~',$row[1]);
  foreach($time_coords as $time_coord) {
    $temp = explode('|',$time_coord);
    $time = $time_coord[0];
    $coord = $time_coord[1];
    // do stuff with $id, and each $time+$coord for that id
  }
}
```